# Finding max number of a row in a 2D array

Tags: c#, arrays, 2d, dimension

I have an 2D array in C# which looks like this:

```
float[,] PlayerStats = {
    //  Lap times Track A
    { 9999.0f, 9999.0f, 9999.0f, 9999.0f, 9999.0f, 9999.0f, 9999.0f },
    //  Lap times Track B
    { 9999.0f, 9999.0f, 9999.0f, 9999.0f, 9999.0f, 9999.0f, 9999.0f },
    //  Lap times Track C
    { 9999.0f, 9999.0f, 9999.0f, 9999.0f, 9999.0f, 9999.0f, 9999.0f }
    };
```

Now after the array got filled at runtime with other values, I would like to display for example the maximum value of Lap times Track B, but I have no clue how to find the max value of row 2 only.

Is there any easy way to achieve this?

Comment: Please tag with the programming language you are using.

Comment: Do you know how to find the max value for any row?  Would you know how to find the max value of a one-dimensional array?

Comment: I need to retrieve the coordinates of the max value in the second row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var max = Enumerable.Range(0, PlayerStats.GetLength(1)).Max(i => PlayerStats[1, i]);
```

Comment: good answer, but some explanation of what it's doing would be helpful.

Comment: Hm I am receiving an IndexOutOfRangeException. Can you explain briefly how it works?

Comment: `Enumerable.Range` gets a range of sequential numbers from `0` to `PlayerStats.GetLength(1)`, which represent the indexes of all the items in the second array of `PlayerStats`. Then it looks at each item using `PlayerStats[1,i]` and gets the Max. So if you're getting an out of range exception, then your `PlayerStats` list must have only 1 or 0 arrays in it (in your question, you specifically asked for the `Max` of the 2nd array).